# Laravel whereIn argument #1 must be of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder, Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder given

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to make a query builder but get this error and I can't get it fixed:

> TypeError : App\StatistiekQuery::App{closure}(): Argument #1 ($query)
> must be of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder,
> Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder given, called in
> Project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php
> on line 347  Project/app/StatistiekQuery.php:120
> Project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:347
> Project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:1009
> Project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php:23
> Project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:1838
> Project/app/StatistiekQuery.php:128
> Project/app/Http/Controllers/ApiExternal/PmDashboardController.php:114
> Project/app/Http/Controllers/ApiExternal/PmDashboardController.php:29
> Project/tests/Feature/ExternalApi/PmDashboardControllerTest.php:175
> Project/tests/Feature/ExternalApi/PmDashboardControllerTest.php:62

This is my App\StatistiekQuery.php:

> $this->query = Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\Builder

This code block starts at line 118 and ends at 129

```
public function filterBcorp(): void
{
    $this->query->whereIn('opdracht_id', function (Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query): void {
        $query->from('opdrachten')
            ->select('id')
            ->whereIn('campagne_id', function (Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query): void {
                $query->from('campagnes')
                    ->select('id')
                    ->whereRaw('LOWER(`naam`) LIKE ?', ['%bcorp%']);
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` and `Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\Builder` to `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`?

Comment: They are all eloquent builders